# Python 3 queue produced by generator, consumed by multiprocesssing

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a generator that will generate more than 1 trillion strings, and I would like to put them in a queue, and let a pool of workers to consume the queue. However I couldn't afford to put the whole 1 trillion strings in my memory and map them to threads.

Generator is very fast, consumption worker is not. I need to maintain the length of queue at a certain level to not blow up my memory. That means I need to figure out a way to pause and restart feeding the queue.

Could anyone provide a hint or so how to accomplish this task in Python 3.4?

Comment: Are we talking an American trillion or a British trillion?

Comment: @user5402 10^12 level. Each string is about 100 characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the maximum size of the queue:

```
q = queue.Queue(10)   # max size of the queue is 10
```

When the queue has attained the maximum size new insertions will block until items are removed from the queue.

Your generator thread can just generate items and put them on the queue. If it gets too far ahead of the consumer threads it will just block.

```
while not done:
   e = generate next item
   q.put(e)         # will block if queue is full
```

See:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

for more info.

Comment: my question is how to dynamically balance the producer and consumer threads in the case when consumers run much faster than the producer? e.g. I dont want to have to manually specify a large max queue size.

Comment: @onesiumus did you find any way to balance the workload between producer and consumer threads?

Comment: Yeah sure. 

The producer, before generating new items, checks if the queue size is below a certain threshold. If yes, it generates an item and adds it to the queue; if not, it pauses, allowing slower consumers time to process items. This strategy allows the producer to dynamically adjust its production rate, preventing the queue from overfilling and conserving memory. Using maxsize is a hard limit that can work, but if you need more  flexibility you can just check the q size.